# Optaplanner debugging groupBy

Tags: optaplanner

I have a java method to create a constraintstream out of all **TeamCalendar** objects (planning entity with pinned=true) that do not follow a given **Preference**.

As a result I would like to have a constraint stream that denotes for each **department** how many of these discrepancies exist. This is the java code:

```
private BiConstraintStream<Department, Integer>  violatedPreferredTeamDays(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(TeamCalendar.class)
        .ifNotExists(Preference.class, 
                Joiners.equal(TeamCalendar::getDate, Preference::getDate),
                Joiners.equal(TeamCalendar::getDepartment, Preference::getDepartment))
        .filter((tc) -> {
            return true;
        })
        .groupBy(TeamCalendar::getDepartment, count())
        .filter((dep, count) -> {
            return true;
        });
}
```

When running this in Debug mode, the first filter (tc -> {return true;}) is entered a total of 20 times, 5 times for each of the 4 departments.
However, after groupBy, the result set seems to be empty. The debugger does not break code execution in that filter, and the penalize function used on this BiConstraintStream does not penalize anything.

I tried some trivial alternatives:

- .groupBy(tc -> tc.getDepartment(), count())
- .groupBy(tc -> { return tc.getDepartment(); }, count() )

as well as alternatives for the count method:

- .groupBy(TeamCalendar::getDepartment, sum(tc -> 1) )
- .groupBy(TeamCalendar::getDepartment, sum(tc -> {return 1;})

But without any improvement.

Am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying engine applies the first filter directly on the `TeamCalendar` and pre-empts the `ifNotExists` call. Therefore you can not use the `filter` to check whether or not the `ifNotExists` has triggered or not.

Constraint Streams are not imperative, and the execution of individual building blocks need not happen in sequence. Constraint Streams can not be inspected using the debugger, unless you understand how the underlying Drools engine evaluates the constraints, and adjust your expectations accordingly.

As to why the `groupBy` result is empty - probably because the `Preference` instance actually exists. If that is not the case, please [file a JIRA](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER), attach a minimal executable code reproducer, and we will look into it.

Comment: Hi Lukás, 
I wasn't aware that the filter was directly applied on all TeamCalendars before applying the ifExists call. It was indeed a question of the Preferences being set incorrectly. 
Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Your constraints will be transformed to an underlying Drools executable model, in which you as a user have no guarantee about the order of operations. For example, from the logic of things, `groupBy()` can only be applied after everything before it has been applied, and that is necessary for correctness. However, filters can be moved around in cases such as yours, while maintaining correctness. In general, with CS, I would suggest to never make assumptions about the execution order of things.